# How do I create this set of multiple files with one command?

Tags: linux, fedora

Given the following sets:

Set 1:

```
abc_data_y1
abc_data_y2
abc_text_y1
abc_text_y2
```

Set 2:

```
xyz_data_y1
xyz_data_y2
xyz_text_y1
xyz_text_y2
```

Can I create all 8 files (in the 2 sets) with ONE command?

If not, can I use ONE command per set to create all 8 files?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: all files are in text format??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on codegolf.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: The feeling that there's an arrangement behind the file names that could be expressed explicitly is not a code golf, in my opinion.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

In shells that support brace expansion (e.g. `bash`), you can make it shorter by

```
touch {abc,xyz}_{data,text}_y{1,2}
```

Comment: You got me by 2 minutes. Gotta love *brace expansion* used to its fullest `:)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to create blank files and then edit them you can create them in one command using *touch* from the command line.

```
touch abc_data_y1 abc_data_y2 abc_text_y1 abc_text_y2 xyz_data_y1 xyz_data_y2 xyz_text_y1 xyz_text_y2
```